# trying to delete the registry key from cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

[image]

I am trying to delete registry key  "s" from command prompt using batch file. I am logged in admin user. But still it showing the "Access Denied".

```
@echo off
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\ADVANCED\FOLDER\SUPERHIDDEN\ /v s /f
pause
exit
```

Comment: have you tested deleting it from regedit.exe - does that work ok?

Comment: Yes sir,i already tried with regedit.exe ,it works. And now my problem is also sovled. Now i have an another.Can u give me any idea to check yes the hide protected operating systrn file option if it is unchecked by any ,with the help of command prompt

Comment: key you want is http://google.com.com/?q=hide+protected+operating+systern+file+registry+key `==> ` http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/961/

Comment: Thank you very much sir,problem solved with ur help, sir , I am a cse btech student,I want to learn the system commands like this using dos,can u refer me any book or another source for it

Comment: I my opinion try http://www.ss64.com, http://www.dostips.com and their forum resources; http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php; Jeb's answers stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:463115+[batch-file] have a look at his top posts on his profile.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command:

```
psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe
```

`psexec` is available from Microsoft here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

You should definitely be careful with this sort of access.

Comment: If that fails with the same error message, you can add it to a .bat file and run it as administrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.it works now. Can u give me any idea to check yes the hide protected operating systrn file option if it is unchecked by any ,with the help of command prompt

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, so I would mark this as answered and ask a new question. :)